# How to make html table like result from grep result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

These are 2 grep statements which I am using to grep date and name from the path and then converting the output to html table format. Can you guys please help me in getting the desired output.

```
grep 'date' /path/to/file | cut -d "=" -f2-7 | cut -d " " -f2-7 | sed -e 's~.*=\(.*\)~<tr><td>\1</td></tr>~;1i\<html><table border="1">' -e '$a\</table>\n</html>';
    
    grep 'name' path/to/file | cut -d " " -f1 | sed -e 's~.*=\(.*\)~<tr><td>\1</td></tr>~;1i\<html><table border="1">' -e '$a\</table>\n</html>';
```

The output I am getting:

```html
<html>
<table border ="1">
<tr><td>Sun Sep 18 23:08:20 PDT 2022</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sun Sep 18 23:15:50 PDT 2022</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sun Sep 18 23:49:08 PDT 2022</td></tr>
</table>
</html>

<html>
<table  border ="1">
<tr><td>aastha</td></tr>
<tr><td>anukriti</td></tr>
<tr><td>aakriti</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Desired Output:

```html
<html><table border="1">
<tr><td>Wed Sep 15 13:27:03 PDT 2021</td><td>aastha</td></tr>
<tr><td>Wed Sep 15 14:36:11 PDT 2021</td><td>kiyo</td></tr>
<tr><td>Wed Sep 15 21:13:12 PDT 2021</td><td>amisha</td></tr>
<tr><td>Thu Sep 16 06:31:22 PDT 2021</td><td>anukriti</td></tr>
<tr><td>Thu Sep 16 09:36:32 PDT 2021</td><td>aakriti</td></tr>
<tr><td>Thu Sep 16 09:39:09 PDT 2021</td><td>harni</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sun Sep 18 23:15:50 PDT 2022</td><td>harshu</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Sample input:

```
name=aastha date=Sun Sep 18 23:49:08 PDT 2022
name=anukriti date=Sun Sep 18 23:15:50 PDT 2022
name=aakriti date=Sun Sep 18 23:08:20 PDT 2022
```

Comment: Put the dates and names in files, then use `paste dates.txt names.txt` to loop over them in parallel.

Comment: Hi the data is in one file only name= aastha date=Sun Sep 18 23:15:50 PDT 2022

Comment: So? Write the output of the two `grep` commands to different files. Or use `awk` to extract the information all at once. instead of using two `sed` commands.

Comment: 2 grep in one command ?

Comment: No, two separate grep commands, just like you currently have. Each writes to a different file.

Comment: @aastha, This all operations which you have done with help of few tools, could be done single handle by `awk` OR `sed` etc, if you could post your samples of input in your question we could try to help here more and that will help you to maintain the code in future also, cheers.

Comment: Hi i have added the sample input in the question yeah can you pls help me how to solve this with `sed` @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @aastha, Sure Aastha, I have added an answer also, cheers. If you have any questions we could discuss in answer's comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ee '1i<html><table border="1">' -e 's~^name=([^ ]*)[^=]*=(.*)~<tr><td>\2</td><td>\1</td></tr>~;${a</table>\n</html>' -e '}' input_file
```

```
$ cat script.sed
1i<html><table border="1">
s~^name=([^ ]*)[^=]*=(.*)~<tr><td>\2</td><td>\1</td></tr>~
$ { 
  a</table>\n</html>
}
$ sed -Ef script.sed input_file
<html><table border="1">
<tr><td>Sun Sep 18 23:49:08 PDT 2022</td><td>aastha</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sun Sep 18 23:15:50 PDT 2022</td><td>anukriti</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sun Sep 18 23:08:20 PDT 2022</td><td>aakriti</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following single `awk` code. We need NOT to use so many tools for this task, this code will help you in terms of maintaining it also for future, since its done in single language.

```
awk -v FS='name=| date=' '
BEGIN{
  print "<html><table border=\"1\">"
}
{
  print "<tr><td>" $NF "</td><td>" $2 "</td></tr>"
}
END{
  print "</table>\n</html>"
}
' Input_file
```

***OR*** same above code in one-liner form will be as follows:

`awk -v FS='name=| date=' 'BEGIN{print "<html><table border=\"1\">"} {print "<tr><td>" $NF "</td><td>" $2 "</td></tr>"} END{print "</table>\n</html>"}'  Input_file`

Comment: Hi thanks for answering actually awk command is not working in my script is it possible in sed?

Comment: @aastha, The samples which you have added(after my request) this code is working on it. Please run it on it directly, don't add/append it to your previous code please. Kindly try it once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tried it its working perfectly fine on the terminal but when I paste this in my script its not giving me any output

Comment: `$table=`awk -v FS='name=| date=' 'BEGIN{print "<html><table border=\"1\">"} {print "<tr><td>" $NF "</td><td>" $2 "</td></tr>"} END{print "</table>\n</html>"}' /path/of/file`;
print "$table";`

Comment: @aastha, So are you passing any variables etc OR you are running it as it is in script? Sorry but without much details couldn't help here.

Comment: @aastha, Ok saw your previous comment which came sametime when I was doing my previous comment. Try it like `table=$(awk -v FS='name=| date=' 'BEGIN{print "<html><table border=\"1\">"} {print "<tr><td>" $NF "</td><td>" $2 "</td></tr>"} END{print "</table>\n</html>"}'  Input_file)` and let me know how it goes then?

Comment: i am passing the command to $table variable and then printing the variable

Comment: @aastha, sure, I have posted code in previous comment, please try the same once and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: `BEGIN failed--compilation aborted`  its giving me this error

Comment: @aastha, when I test command `table=$(awk -v FS='name=| date=' 'BEGIN{print "<html><table border=\"1\">"} {print "<tr><td>" $NF "</td><td>" $2 "</td></tr>"} END{print "</table>\n</html>"}'  Input_file)` it works perfectly fine for the samples which are present in `Input_file` which I passed to `awk` command. Are you running it same as I shown?

Comment: its a perl and bash script

Comment: with .cgi extension

Comment: @aastha, To be honest that looks to me a different question, which you can open, Since question was to get the output in HTML format this works fine IMHO. For any other future new/related question kindly open a new question with details. Let me know cheers.

Comment: can this question be solved with sed command?

Comment: sed command is working perfectly fine

Comment: @aastha, yes but trust me as I mentioned already, we can do it in a single `awk` command we need NOT to use so many commands/codes, hence I posted `awk` code single handedly its running fine and generating output.

Comment: pls help I have to submit this by midnight and I am stuck here 

Comment: @aastha, I am trying to help you by giving you a working code and suggesting you NOT to use too many tools for a single task which is being done in a single shot. Please run my code and it will help you and trust me its quite easy to manage, cheers.

Comment: I agree with you but its only working on the terminal and not in the script . Anyways thankyou so much :)

Comment: when I try to use awk command in my script so that it prints the output on html page awk command is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<html>` and `<table>` tags from the `sed` commands.

Run the first command with its output to `dates.txt`. It should just put the `<tr>` tag at the beginning of each result line.

Run the second commands with its output to `names.txt`. It should just put the `</tr>` tag at the end of each result line.

Then use `paste` to concatenate them side by side. Use simple `printf` statements to add the `<html>` and `<table>` tags around it.

```
grep 'date' /path/to/file | cut -d "=" -f2-7 | cut -d " " -f2-7 | sed 's~.*=\(.*\)~<tr><td>\1</td>~' > dates.txt
grep 'name' path/to/file | cut -d " " -f1 | sed 's~.*=\(.*\)~<td>\1</td></tr>~' > names.txt

printf '<html>\n<table border="1">\n'
paste dates.txt names.txt
printf '</table>\n</html>\n'
```

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unterminated `s' command
i am geeting this eeror while runing names command